# Enum not recognized even though it is included

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am fairly new to C++, and am having an annoying bug: this previously functional code has stopped working for some reason. Upon compilation the first errors I get are shown below. I think that for some reason it isn't recognizing the enum type `Material`, even though it is imported.

```
1>...\chunk.h(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'terrain'
1>...\chunk.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\chunk.h(10): error C2065: 'chunkWidth' : undeclared identifier
1>...\chunk.h(10): error C2065: 'chunkWidth' : undeclared identifier
1>...\chunk.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\world.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'get'
1>...\world.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\world.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>...\world.h(14): warning C4183: 'get': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>...\world.h(6): error C2011: 'World' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          ...\world.h(6) : see declaration of 'World'
1>...\world.cpp(9): error C2027: use of undefined type 'World'
1>          ...\world.h(6) : see declaration of 'World'
```

**Chunk.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "main.h"

class Chunk {
    private:
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
    public:
        Chunk(int xRelToSpawn, int yRelToSpawn);
        Material terrain[chunkWidth][chunkWidth];
        int getXpos();
        int getYpos();
};
```

**main.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "World.h"

//const int gridSizeX = 30;
//const int gridSizeY = 30;
const int chunkWidth = 15;
const int chunkHeight = 15;
extern int viewportX;
extern int viewportY;
const int viewportWidth = 15;
const int viewportHeight = 15;

enum Material{SAND, WATER};

extern World world = World();
```

**World.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include "main.h"
#include "Chunk.h"
using namespace std;

class World {
    private:
        vector<Chunk> chunks;
    public:
        World();
        ~World();
        bool chunkExists(int x, int y);
        //returns material for absolute coordinates
        Material get(int x, int y);
        //returns world coordinates for given chunk coordinates
        int* getAbsCoords(int chunkIndex, int x, int y);
        int* getChunkCoords(int x, int y);
        Chunk getChunk(int index);
        int getChunkIndex(int x, int y);
        int chunkIndexAbove(int chunkIndex);
        int chunkIndexBelow(int chunkIndex);
        int chunkIndexLeft(int chunkIndex);
        int chunkIndexRight(int chunkIndex);
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you know what extern does?

Comment: I can assure you that I do not have complete knowledge of what `extern` does or is for.

Comment: My suspicion is that World.h includes Chunk.h, so you have circular includes.

Comment: That is the case, but I am a novice, and unsure how to fix this. I'll upload the source for `World.h`. I tried using `#ifndef` and `#endif`, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: @FracturedRetina: if your question was addressed (and it was, removing the `extern` before the `enum`, You give helpful answers and upvote, and the best answer with a checkmark.  If you have _additional_ problems, make a new post.  It's usually considered rude to rewrite the post to have a different answer.  However, since the only answer was deleted, I guess we can let this one slide for now.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I agree, but even after removing the `extern`, the error messages were **exactly the same**, so it is likely the same problem

Comment: I feel you dumped too much advanced techniques into your code: extern,  nested circular include dependency, dynamic array (e.g. Material terrain[chunkWidth][chunkWidth];) ... maybe some redesign and simplification would help.

Comment: For instance, you can simply remove the #include in clunk.h by make it a simple struct: struct Chunk {
        int xpos;
        int ypos;}; and forget about the encapsulation, have your code compiles first.

Comment: @cppinitiator: Agreed, should I then delete this question?

Comment: You can keep and update it so I can comment until your code compiles :)

Comment: @cppinitiator: Thanks, that's what I love about stackexchange: helpful, awesome, and smart people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere you have

```
#include "chunk.h"
```

So the processor stops that file and starts reading chunk.h instead:

```
#pragma once
#include "main.h"
```

So the processor starts reading main.h  instead:

```
#pragma once
#include "World.h"
```

So the processor starts reading World.h  instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include "main.h" //main.h was pragma'd so this is ignored
#include "Chunk.h" //chunk.h was pragma'd so this is ignored
using namespace std;

class World {
    private:
        vector<Chunk> chunks; //here, the compiler should be confused
                              //it hasn't seen what a "Chunk" is yet.
```

You have circular dependencies.  The way to fix this is simple in theory, but tricky in practice.  First: Put all of your types/globals/functions in an order:

```
Material //material needs nothing else to be defined
Chunk //chunk needs material, nothing else to be defined
World //world needs Chunk _and_ material to be defined
extern World world = World(); //needs World to be defined
```

Then edit your headers so that the data is in this order.  Namely, the header containing `Material` should NOT include the header containing Chunk, World, or `world`.  And the header containing `Chunk` should NOT include the header containing `World` or `world`.

In your case, the *types* don't have circular dependencies, so this is relatively easy.  Move `Material` to the chunk header (or it's own header) so that the chunk header needs no includes, and nothing needs to include the main header.

```
Chunk.h //contains Material and Chunk
World.h //contains World
Main.h  //contains extern World world
```

---

I don't think that `extern World world = World()` works in a header.  I think you'll have to remove the `= World()`, and then in a cpp file, put the line:

```
World world;
```

This is the actual global variable.  The `extern` in the header merely lets all the other files know that this variable exists somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice for avoiding circular includes is:

- If you're using a Microsoft compiler, add `#pragma once` at the start of the file.
- To work with any compiler, at the start of the .h file:

  #ifndef YOURFILENAME_H

  #define YOURFILENAME_H

  #include "World.h"

  ... 
  body of the .h file
  ...

  #endif //ndef YOURFILENAME_H